# Vertica: Running manual DBD from Management Console

Tags: vertica

When I run a manual DBD from **Vertica Management Console** ( only build/not deploy automatically ) , the resulting script always defaults to **ksafe 0**

( 1st and last line in resulting script : `select mark_design_ksafe(0);` )

I always select **ksafe 1** in the general tab. I suspect that this is a bug?

Has anyone seen the same behavior?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How many nodes are in your cluster?

Comment: Like @Kermit said, you only will get a K-safety of 1 if you have at least 3 nodes up and running.

Comment: Hi Kermit, Up_one   We do have a 3 node cluster and the current KSAFE level  is 1 . ( I've used the management console wizard to create projections before and all of those had a buddy projection and kept KSAFE(1) . I have not yet tried to create another comprehensive Design ( only build ) from admintools. Any idea what might be wrong with MC ? ( or ... any idea what I did wrong :S )